# How do I validate the length and presence of password in this rc-form?

Tags: reactjs, rc-form

I am building an admin login form with an email and a password field.
I would like to validate the length of the password and ensure that the password field isn't empty before the form is submitted.

```
import { createForm, formShape } from 'rc-form'
import React ,{Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class LoginForm extends React.Component {

static propTypes = {
 form: formShape,
};

onSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 this.props.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('ok', values);
  } else {
    console.log('error', error, values);
  }
 })
}

render() {
const {getFieldProps, getFieldError} = this.props.form
const errors = getFieldError('password')
const {form} = this.props
return (
  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <div>
      <div>
        Enter password
      </div>
      <input
      placeholder='Enter your password'
      {...getFieldProps('password', {
        validate: [
          {
            trigger: 'onBlur',
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            trigger: ['onBlur', 'onChange'],
            rules: [
              {
                type: 'password',
                min: 5,
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      } ) }
      />
      <div>
        {errors ? errors.join(',') : null}
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Connect</button>
    </div>
  </form>
)
}
}

export default createForm()(LoginForm)
```

I expect an error message if the password is less than 5 characters or is absent but I currently don't get any errors message.

Answer (score 0):

The rule for password length should have a type of `string` not `password`.

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rpvgmh